# Generalize two similar methods that have different unary operators

Tags: java, string, concatenation, character

Suppose I have the following implementations

```
private static String encryptPassword(String password) {
    String encryptedPassword = "";
    char[] chars = password.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword.concat(String.valueOf(++c));
    }
    return encryptedPassword;
}

private static String decryptPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
    String decryptedPassword = "";
    char[] chars = encryptedPassword.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        decryptedPassword = decryptedPassword.concat(String.valueOf(--c));
    }
    return decryptedPassword;
}
```

These methods do very simple stuff that it will increase each character in a string by 1 and this process is considered as encryption. As a contrast, the process of decryption will decrease the value.

I can see that these two methods are pretty much the same, except the unary operators.

How can I generalize these two methods?

Furthermore, I also prefer streaming processing to looping. If you have any ideas regarding this point, please posting as well.

Comment: Pass in either `+1` or `-1` and add this to the char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the Java 8 Functional programming features to provide the behavior expressed as a Function as a method argument.

Here's how your logic can be implemented using Stream API, the additional argument the method expects is of type [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html) (*which is a function expecting a single `int` argument, and producing `int` value as the result*).

```
public static String processPassword(String password,
                                     IntUnaryOperator operator) {
    return password.chars()
        .map(operator)
        .collect(
            StringBuilder::new,
            StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
            StringBuilder::append
        )
        .toString();
}
```

And here's how you can call this method from the client code:

```
String encrypted = processPassword("fooBar", i -> ++i);
System.out.println(encrypted);
String decrypted = processPassword(encrypted, i -> --i);
System.out.println(decrypted);
```

*Output:*

```
gppCbs
fooBar
```

But, it's error-prone (for instance, a function with `++i` can be accidentally instead of a function with `--i`), and has a maintainability issue because you might end up with repeating these functions in several places, so it would be harder to change them.

The better approach would be to abstract the client from the actual implementations of the functions used in encrypting/decrypting and store these functions in one place, so that they can be easily modified without effecting the rest of the code.

This can be achieved by introducing an `enum`.

```
public enum ProcessType {
    ENCRYPT(i -> ++i),
    DECRYPT(i -> --i);
    
    private IntUnaryOperator operator;

    // constructor, getter
}
```

And we need to modify the method shown above to make it consume an enum constant instead of a function:

```
public static String processPassword(String password,
                                     ProcessType type) {
    return password.chars()
        .map(type.getOperator())
        .collect(
            StringBuilder::new,
            StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
            StringBuilder::append
        )
        .toString();
}
```

And that's how the client code would look like:

```
String encrypted = processPassword("fooBar", ProcessType.ENCRYPT);
System.out.println(encrypted);
String decrypted = processPassword(encrypted, ProcessType.DECRYPT);
System.out.println(decrypted);
```

*Output:*

```
gppCbs
fooBar
```

Comment: What an elegant look!

Answer (score 2):

Define a enum to specify operation type, based on the enum you can apply business logic.

```
private static enum OperationType {
    ENCRYPTION(1), DECRYPTION(-1);

    int val;

    private OperationType(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

private static String process(final String data, final OperationType operationType) {
    final char[] chars = data.toCharArray();

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : chars) {
        builder.append((char)(ch + operationType.val));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

To work with streams, you can use string chars method like below.

```
private static String process(final String data, final OperationType operationType) {
    
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Stream<Character> charStream = data.chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i);
    charStream.forEach(ch -> builder.append((char)(ch + operationType.val)));

    return builder.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two methods `encryptPassword` and `decryptPassword` is the value that you are adding to each `char` in the `String`. Therefore I suggest adding a third method that takes two parameters: the first is the `String` to encrypt (or decrypt) and the second is the value to add to each `char`. In the below code, I called this third method `adjustPassword`.

As described in the book [Java by Comparison](https://java.by-comparison.com/) I suggest keeping methods `encryptPassword` and `decryptPassword` and have those methods call method `adjustPassword` with the appropriate value. That way, when you want to encrypt or decrypt a password, you don't need to remember what value to pass for the required operation.

Explanations after the code.

```java
public class Solution {

    private static String encryptPassword(String password) {
        return adjustPassword(password, 1);
    }

    private static String decryptPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
        return adjustPassword(encryptedPassword, -1);
    }

    private static String adjustPassword(String password, int adjustment) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(password.length());
        password.chars()
                .map(c -> c + adjustment)
                .forEach(i -> sb.append((char) i));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "George";
        System.out.println("Original: " + password);
        String encrypted = encryptPassword(password);
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decryptPassword(encrypted));
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
Original: George
Encrypted: Hfpshf
Decrypted: George
```

- Since Java 9, class `String` has method `chars()` which returns an `IntStream` since `char` is essentially an `int`.
- Class `StringBuilder` has overloaded `append` methods. In the `forEach` method, the type of the method parameter, i.e. `i`, is `int`, hence the cast to `char`, otherwise method `adjustPassword` would return a `String` that only contained digits.

Comment: Worth to note that this Stream is broken in parallel, and such usage of side-effects is **discouraged** by the [Stream API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).